# Coq variable exists in list

Tags: coq, formal-verification

I have problem with proving existential variable in list. How can I prove something like this:

```
Lemma exists_in_list_helper: forall (X : Type) (a : X) (P : X -> Prop),
        (exists b : X, In b [a] -> P b) ->
        P a.
Proof.
Admitted.
```

I have another question. How can I do case analysis over the values in a list (if it exists in this part of the list or not)? This is the main lemma I'm proving. Any help appreciated:

```
Lemma in_list: forall (X : Type) (a : X) l (P : X -> Prop),
        (a :: l <> [] /\ exists b : X, In b (a :: l) -> P b) ->
        (P a /\ l = []) \/
        (P a /\ l <> [] /\ exists b : X, In b l -> P b) \/
        (P a /\ l <> [] /\ forall b : X, In b l -> ~ P b) \/
        (~ P a /\ l <> [] /\ exists b : X, In b l -> P b).
Proof.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first lemma doesn't seem probable: we know that there exists a `b` such that `P b` holds iff `b \in [a]`. However, we don't know if `b \in [a]` holds, so it seems difficult to prove. You can maybe see your statement as:

```
Lemma exists_in_list_helper (X : Type) (a : X) (P : X -> Prop) :
        (exists b : X, a = b -> P b) ->
        P a.
```

Then, it doesn't immediately follow that `a = b`. You may want a lemma such as:

```
Lemma in1 T (x y : T) : In x [y] <-> x = y.
Proof.
split; intros H.
+ now apply in_inv in H; case H.
+ now rewrite H; constructor.
Qed.
```

Regarding your second question, I am not sure I fully understand the intent of your lemma. Usually, one wants to have:

```
forall x l, x \in l \/ x \notin l
```

but this requires decidability for the equality over the type of `x`, see Lemma `in_dec`. If you split a list `l` in `l1, l2`, then it follows that:

```
x \in l1 ++ l2 <-> x \in l1 \/ x \in l2
```

which allows for case reasoning. More interesting facilities are given by math-comp's path.v, which allows to deduce in a convenient way:

```
x \in l -> { l1, l2 & l = l1 ++ [x] ++ l2 }
```

where `{ x & P x}` is the `Type` version of `exists x, P x`.

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer. I have another question. I get "Impossible to unify" error while using apply. I have seen that we can use 'pattern' tactic but I couldn't properly use it. I have proven the following: ~ (exists b : X, In b l -> P b) ->
        (forall b : X, In b l -> ~ P b).

Comment: I used pattern (forall b : X, In b l -> ~ P b) which generated a 'fun' but again couldn't use apply my_lemma to replace forall with ~exists... Can you help me how I can properly use pattern to guide the apply tactic?

Comment: @saeedM I think this deserves another question, I am not sure what you are trying to do. Note that the replacement you are trying to do may not hold in general for constructive logic.

Answer (score -1):

For the first one, I'd say you might also need the fact that equality on `X` is decidable: either `a = b` and you can substitute, or `a <> b` and you get a contradiction, but you need to be able to perform such case analysis.

For the second one, you can remove the `a :: l <> []` part, it is always true and doesn't give you anything. And I'm pretty sure you also need decidable equality too (for the same reasons).